Plotting heatmap on human using python
I have a dataset with 2 columns: 1. body part - head, left wrist, back, toe, leg 2. value - 50, 60, 70, 500, 600. The higher the value, the color will change from light orange to red. How to do it in python when I try to show the heatmap on human body.
I am imagining like this https://images.app.goo.gl/8fsgZsfwgN4hwD6Z6
This is body part I am using
https://images.app.goo.gl/vqhKkqUMZNRBrhDX9
not working
To create a heatmap on a human body image based on the values in your dataset, you can use the Matplotlib library along with an image overlay technique. Here's an example of how you can do it in Python:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

# Load the human body image
img = mpimg.imread('human_body_image.png')

# Sample data
body_parts = ['head', 'left wrist', 'back', 'toe', 'leg']
values = [50, 60, 70, 500, 600]

# Define color map
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Oranges')  # Choose a colormap ('Oranges' in this case)

# Normalize values to range between 0 and 1
norm = plt.Normalize(min(values), max(values))

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Show the human body image
ax.imshow(img)

# Overlay the heatmap on the image
for i in range(len(body_parts)):
    x = i * 100  # Adjust the x-coordinate based on the body part position
    y = 100  # Adjust the y-coordinate based on the body part position
    size = values[i] / 10  # Adjust the size based on the value
    color = cmap(norm(values[i]))  # Get the color based on the value
    ax.scatter(x, y, color=color, s=size, alpha=0.7)

# Set the title
ax.set_title('Heatmap on Human Body')

# Remove axis ticks and labels
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

In this example, you need to replace 'human_body_image.png' with the path to your own human body image

Specify please what is not working. Do you get an error when executing? Doesnt it show the color right? Wrong position? Next time try to describe your problem more accurately and what you want to achieve. I see several issues with the code the AI provided you with that need to be tweaked according to your needs.
